# How to query the "Exposed Api" for all users calendars in a Tenant?

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

I want to be able to - from a crohn job on a 3rd. party server - query and modify all users in my the Tenants (organisation) calendars - but i just end up with a "Application ID URI" that i don't know what to do with.

No matter how i query the microsoft graph API i get "Invalid Audience" and the docs on the subject doesn't really seem to highlight how exactly to specify the correct "audience" or what a "resource" actually entails.

These are the steps i have taken in the Azure Active Directory portal:

I use the Client Credentials Grant flow so i can access with a Cron and not through a user. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow

1) Registered an application in the portal. So i get some ID's (anonymized here)

```
Application (client) ID
:
51ed7b6d-d33e-491e
Directory (tenant) ID
:
c181f4f3-912b-4acf-
Object ID
:
3f52a799-f2ab-4161-a81c
```

2) Created a secret so i can provide that together with the Application id to get a token.

3) Given "Api Application Permissions" to https://graph.microsoft.com/Calendars.ReadWrite.

4) "Exposed an Api" and called it's scope "readwrite calendars" so the Application ID URI with the scope end up being: api://51ed7b6d-d33e-491e-9d40-1/readwritecalendars

5) Authorized the API to the application with the Application (client) ID from step 1 so i don't need admin consent to query.

Problem is now i just end up with an "Application ID URI", okay how i do i exactly query my for the calendars then?

I am using https://github.com/TheNetworg/oauth2-azure here:

I am able to successfully get a token:

```
$provider = new \TheNetworg\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Azure([
            'clientId'     => env('OAUTH_APP_ID'),
            'clientSecret' => env('OAUTH_APP_PASSWORD'),
            'redirectUri'  => 'http://www.google.dk'
        ]);
        $provider->tenant = 'secret';
        $token = $provider->getAccessToken('client_credentials', [
            'resource' => 'https://graph.windows.net',
        ]);


        $provider->urlAPI = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/";
        $provider->resource = "https://graph.microsoft.com/";


return $token ;
```

Gives me:

```
{
"token_type": "Bearer",
"ext_expires_in": "3600",
"expires_on": "1562669834",
"not_before": "1562665934",
"resource": "https://graph.windows.net/",
"access_token": "longstringofnumbers",
"expires": 1562269224
}
```

There is no "Aud" or "Audience" field returned.

This i where i get confused, how exactly do i form a link, how do i say that i want to query all calendars with the token?

Looking at the outlook graph documentation it specifies i need to query like this (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-calendars?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http):

```
GET /me/calendars
```

This doesn't really make sense to me as "me" seems to imply a user, i am trying to query stuff in a tenant not tied to a specific user?

Anyway if i try to query like:

```
$provider->get('me/calendars',$token);
```

Or different combinations of this i just get:

```
Access token validation failure. Invalid audience.
```

To sum it all up: how do i actually query the API to list/modify calendars, what is the actual endpoint i have to hit? And where do i put the actual query?

Thanks in advance!

A result would be a JSON object instead of the error message. A successful return to the query. In this case a list of all users calendars, or a "successfully updated" after modifying a calendar.

Answer (score 0):

In Azure AD you can specify "API Permissions" for an app registration. If you want to query all calendars with one access token you should use "[Application permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-daemon-app-registration)".

*Point 4 is for other types of applications like Office Add-Ins.*

For all request you can use the default Graph endpoint `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/`. So if you wan't to query a user calendar you should use this:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/<UserId or UPN>/calendar
```

Comment: Thanks but i have already given Application Permissions and not "delegated permissions". After getting the token i get "Invalid Audience" no matter what i try to request (/me  or /users or whatever). I am not sure if i have to send the scope or the resource "api://51ed7b6d-d33e-491e-9d40-1/readwritecalendars" along somehow?

Comment: You need to pass the scopes you need when you request your token. https://github.com/TheNetworg/oauth2-azure#advanced-flow

Answer (score 0):

Got it working with:

```
$provider = new \TheNetworg\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Azure([
        'clientId'     => env('OAUTH_APP_ID'),
        'clientSecret' => env('OAUTH_APP_PASSWORD'),
    ]);
    $provider->tenant = env('AZURE_TENANT');
    $provider->urlAPI = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/";
    $provider->resource = "https://graph.microsoft.com/";
    $token = $provider->getAccessToken('client_credentials', [
        'resource' => 'https://graph.microsoft.com',
    ]);
    $currentCalendarEvents = $provider->get('users/some@some.com/calendars/Calendar/events?$top=1000', $token);
```

The $provider->resource and urlapi has to be set before the request off course as written in the docs: https://github.com/TheNetworg/oauth2-azure#microsoft-graph